# Susy at-breakpoint max-width media query

Tags: compass-sass, susy-compass

I'm trying to create a media query that has `max-width: 600px` using the `@include at-breakpoint` mixin.

```
.selector {
  @include at-breakpoint(4, 600px){
    // ...
  }
}
```

Will output the following media query:

```
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  // ...
}
```

I was under the impression that the `at-breakpoint` mixin accepts 3 arguments, being: min-width, lay-out and max-width.

But when using this:

```
.selector {
  @include at-breakpoint(1px, 4, 600px){
    // ...
  }
}
```

I get the following compile error:

```
Mixin at-breakpoint takes 2 arguments but 3 were passed
```

But I'm not getting any errors when I use this, even though `$tablet-layout` is passing 3 arguments.

```
.selector {
  @include at-breakpoint($tablet-layout){
    // ...
  }    
}


$tablet-width:              600px;
$tablet-columns:             12;
$tablet-sidebar-columns:     4;

$desktop-width:              780px;
$desktop-columns:            12;
$desktop-sidebar-columns:   4;

$tablet-layout:       $tablet-width $tablet-columns $desktop-width;
$desktop-layout:      $desktop-width $desktop-columns $tablet-width;
```

**So my question is:** what is the correct way to get a `max-width: 600px` media query in Susy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you need to do it without the commas:

```
@include at-breakpoint(4 600px); // max-width: 600px;
@include at-breakpoint(1px 4 600px) // min-width: 1px; max-width: 4px;
```

That's why your other combined variables work - they all get passed as a single list argument.

Comment: Oh god... I've been using Susy for awhile and didn't noticed there where no comma's. So easy :). Thanks for the help, appreciated.